# PHP: Prevent nested try-catch from catching a specific error

Tags: php, try-catch

I have a PHP script which needs to execute a callback function and catch a specific type of error.

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception{}

function doStuff(callable $callback){

    try{
        $callback();
    }
    catch(MyException $e){
        #Deal with it
    }
}

?>
```

The callback function can use a try-catch which will prevent my exception being bubbled up. How can I allow the callback function to implement try-catch blocks but not allow it to catch MyException?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Use case?  I don't see the reason behind not allowing a callback to handle their own exceptions, this callback would have been the one to throw the exception in the first place.

Comment: @Devon I suspect the use-case is that the callback uses his library, and the library throws the exceptions.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to not make it a subclass of `Exception`. Then if his code has `catch(Exception $e)`, it won't catch it.

Comment: @Barmar That is correct. I'd like the callback to have no knowledge of what the error means. I just want to callback to halt and return back to the library so it can handle the problem.

Comment: That idea won't work, PHP requires that anything thrown be `Exception` or a subclass of it.

Comment: @Barmar I did think of that but PHP won't allow any class to be thrown that isn't extended from Exception

Comment: I don't think your design is really feasible. The inner function needs to be able to intercept anything that might exit from it, e.g. to close files, abort a DB transaction, etc. If your exception could bypass his `catch()`, that would violate its integrity.

Comment: I think you may need to just document that the callback has to check for `MyException` and rethrow it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I've read the question wrong - I can not think of a use case where this is required - but I think something like this will work:

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception {}

/*
 * This method is in the library. It's not in your control
 */
function doStuff(callable $callback) {
    try {
        $callback();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

/*
 * We want to do something, but not let any MyException pass through to doStuff()
 */
doStuff(function() {
    try {
        connect('mysql:dbname=IDoNotExist;host=127.0.0.1', 'batman', 'robin');
    } catch(MyException $e) {
        return; // Do nothing with MyException, continue as if it didn't happen
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e); // Not an instance of MyException ... let the library handle it
    }
});

/*
 * This is dummy code that will throw MyException if the username and password are incorrect
 */
function connect($dsn, $username, $password) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        throw new MyException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm assuming, by reading the comments and your responses, that `doStuff()` is some library call that you pass a `callable` to. If the code inside your callback catches a `MyException` you want to completely ignore this.

The code above will completely ignore `MyException` as if nothing happened. Although I would never advocate such a solution.

Comment: I do want MyException to be picked up by the try-catch in the doStuff() function. I was trying to prevent that specific exception from being caught by any of the code inside the callback to ensure it always bubbles. Essentially I don't want the callback to override my error handling.

Comment: From everyone's comments it looks like I need to rethink the whole way that this works. It might be better to have try-catches in the callback and return true/false to show if the callback succeeds. Thanks for your help everyone. I will think it through a little more and hopefully come up with a more proper solution.